# /etc/mtab as a symlink on Centos6

Tags: centos, symlink

On a Centos6 system, can I delete /etc/mtab (the file) and create it as a symlink to /proc/self/mounts? As I understand it, starting from Centos7 (and other newer distros), the file /etc/mtab no longer exists. I need to support some legacy Centos6 machines.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, starting from Centos7 (and other newer distros), the file /etc/mtab no longer exists.

It exists as a symlink which points to `../proc/self/mounts`.

> On a Centos6 system, can I delete /etc/mtab (the file) and create it as a symlink to /proc/self/mounts?

Why would you want to do that? That might work.